# CMSIS driver for my ARM Cortex M4 STM32L1xx Series MCU?

Tags: cmsis

I have STM32L1 series  I want to use CMSIS driver for my application but my device does not  Support to CMSIS Driver, There is another STM Family i.e STM32F1 Series MCU  which is supports to CMSIS Driver  So is there any solution to use STM32F1 CMSIS driver to STM32L1 Series MCU ???

Answer (score 1):

Use the SPL for your series MCU. CMSIS is included to it.
Path: %dir%\STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.3.1\Libraries\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L1xx and %dir%\STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.3.1\Libraries\CMSIS\Include

Second option - use STM32CubeL1, but I did not use it and don't know how.

Comment: What is SPL ? I didn't get this could u please explain me ?

Comment: Standart Peripherials Library. You can download it from site of STMicroelectronics. 
https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-libraries/stsw-stm32077.html

Comment: This library contains startup files for mcu, headers and api files for any peripheral module.

Comment: If the answer helped you, mark it as a solution, please.

Comment: Ok but how to use this library means where actually copy this (STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.3.1) directory ?

Comment: In IAR EWARM, for example, need copy files:
%SPLdir%\Libraries\CMSIS\Include\core_cm4.h
%SPLdir%\Libraries\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L1xx\Include\stm32l1xx.h 
%SPLdir%\Libraries\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L1xx\Include\system_stm32l1xx.h 
%SPLdir%\Libraries\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L1xx\Source\Templates\iar\%startupfile_for_your_line_of_device%
to project's directory and include them in open project from IAR.

Comment: And files contained in folders:
%SPLdir%\Libraries\STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver\inc
%SPLdir%\Libraries\STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src

Comment: It will also be necessary to write your own SystemInit function or take file contained it to the folder: %SPLdir%\Libraries\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L1xx\Source\Template‌​s\system_stm32l1xx.c

Comment: In main.c write: #include "stm32f4xx.h" 
#include "system_stm32f4xx.h" 
#include "core_cm4.h"

Answer (score -1):

Sol is the way to go.

Alternatively, use coide and it offers cmsis start up.

Short of that, you can hand code the start up files from a generic cmx project. I did that for stm32m4 chips on an old uvsion / rvmdk combo.

Comment: Hey ruslan is there any book or website to use this SPL step by Step ?